# Загрузка проекта Symfony на хостинг

Tags: php, symfony, маршрутизация, hosting, symfony3

Как правильно загрузить проект Symfony на хостинг?

На локалке при включении режим разработки у меня все нормально работает. Но если копирую файлы на хостинг то не работает роутинг и приходится писать ссылки в виде "site.com/web/app_dev.php/someroute", так же как при отключенном режиме разработки на локалке. Как сделать что все работало?

Comment: Что за хостинг? Поддерживает ли указание правил перенаправления в .htaccess? Что именно происходит после заливки на хостинг?

Answer (score 5):

Для тех кто не может настроить Framework Symfony2, Symfony3:

1. В папке www создаем .htaccess и пишем в него:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/.*$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [QSA,L]
   ```
2. В папке web находим .htaccess (который поставляется с symfony) и комментируем строчку

   ```
   Options -MultiViews
   ```
3. После этого всё должно работать нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Узнайте у хостера, у вас Apache или nginx.

Потом по инструкции:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html